# Which compound will undergo dehydration more readily?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Which will undergo dehydration more readily under acidic conditions, alpha-hydroxy ketone or beta-hydroxy ketone?

My guess would be the second one will undergo dehydration with ease relative to the first one although I am not sure. One reason that comes to my mind is that the carbocation formed in the first one will be destabilized by the ketone. Is my guess correct? If yes, am I correct in my reasoning too? Or are there any other dimensions that I am missing to look into.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds good, Tony!

Comment: @Tony also alpha-hydroxyketo will be relatively  more stable than beta due to a Hydrogen bonding, which will be better in the former compound since OH and O of keto will be closer. This should hinder the enolisation of alpha compund further.